# Recursion inside a loop time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have created this algorithm to solve a problem using the backtracking strategy. The problem consists on:

> Given a set A of n integers and two integer values, m and c. Calculate all subsets of A, of m elements, that the sum of their values is c.

**The algorithm (in java)**:

```
public class Algorithm {

    private List<Integer> a;
    private int m;
    private int c;

    /**
     * @param a Initial set
     * @param m Maximum number of elements stored in the subset
     * @param c Desired sum
     */
    Algorithm(List<Integer> a, int m, int c) {
        this.m = m;
        this.c = c;
        this.a = a;

        findSubsets(0, new int[m], 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * @param i Index to go through the initial set
     * @param subset Solution candidate
     * @param level Current number of elements stored in the subset
     * @param sum  Current sum of the elements stored in the subset
     */
    private void findSubsets(int i, int[] subset, int level, int sum) {

        // Base case
        if (level == m) {
            if (sum == c) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subset));
            }
        }

        // Exploration
        else {
            while (i < a.size()) {
                subset[level] = a.get(i);

                findSubsets(i + 1, subset, level + 1, sum + a.get(i));

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The time complexity:**

With this solution, I have experimentally determined that when m tends to n, the complexity tends to O(2^n). However, after reading through guides on how to calculate the time complexity, I am yet unable to determine this result mathematically. I am also highly interested in the average case, and I am very lost on how to calculate it.

I knwo this might be a newbie question, but I would highly appreciate if someone could lend me a hand! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm computes every subset, assuming m=n. For each `0<=i<n`, you double the number of subsets that were possible at `i-1`, because there are two cases for each subset at level `i-1` to bring them to level `i`: add `a[i]`, or don't.

For example, if i=2 and there are 4 possible subsets (eg {}, {A},{B},{AB}), then for i=3 there will be 4 subsets that don't contain `a[3]` (same as before), and 4 new subsets that do contain `a[3]` (eg {C}, {AC},{BC},{ABC}), for a total of 8.

Since we double for each `i<n`, the total number of possible subsets is `2^n`, in the case where n=m.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your algorithm will be `O(m * 2^m)` as you consider all subsets of `A` which is less than or equal `m` as you cosnider the `level` for each of them!. The multiplying to `m` is for summing the value of each subset.

Comment: The algorithm does implicitly stop since the `else` block is not called after `level==m`.